# Is it possible to override the return of an Object in C#?

Tags: c#, object, return

I have a LiteralObject class and by default it inherits from System.Object. This is how the class looks like:

```
    public LiteralObject(Object value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    private Object value;
    public Object getValue() { return value; }
```

To get the value of a LiteralObject object:

```
LiteralObject x = new LiteralObject(23);
Console.WriteLine(x.getvalue());
```

What I want is this:

```
LiteralObject x = new LiteralObject(23);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Is there a way to override the returning of a System.Object object? or is there any other way to get what I want? Bytheway, overriding ToString() is not the solution I'm looking for. And the object passed into the constructor is of the same type with its parent/base class

Comment: For your second example, shouldn't it still be `x.getValue()`?

Comment: `LiteralObject x = new LiteralObject(23);`, this is assigment, not returning.

Comment: What I want is to return the value of a LiteralObject without using the getValue() method. I just want to return the value by using the instance of Literal Object just like in the 2nd example.

Comment: @glennmark That doesn't make sense. `x` is a `LiteralObject` type. You can't change that type to become what you pass into the constructor

Comment: What if the object passed into the constructor is of the same class with its parent or base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort of do that using implicit cast operators. However it doesn't work on `object` since you can't perform implicit conversion on `object` (or any other ancestor class). To get around that we can use generics:

```
class LiteralObject<T>
{
    public LiteralObject(T initialValue)
    {
        this.value = initialValue;
    }
    private T value;

    public T getValue()
    { 
        return value; 
    }

    static public implicit operator T(LiteralObject<T> source)
    {
        return source.getValue();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void PrintInteger(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var o = new LiteralObject<int>(23);
        PrintInteger(o);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
23
```

[Example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ydnnU3)